# Classify items for an HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json file that i turned into an html table using javascript. I want to be able to sort through the arrays of my json file to only show specific items when i click a button.

I have read online about the onclick() function in javascript but i don't know how to integrate it in a function to only show certain items of my json file in the html table.

```
var petsData = [{
    name: "Purrsloud",
    species: "Cat",
    favFoods: ["wet food", "dry food", "<strong>any</strong> food"],
    birthYear: 2016,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Barksalot",
    species: "Dog",
    birthYear: 2008,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/dog-1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Meowsalot",
    species: "Cat",
    favFoods: ["tuna", "catnip", "celery"],
    birthYear: 2012,
    photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-1.jpg"
  }
];

var tableStart = `
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Species</th>
      <th>Birth Year</th>
      <th>Favorite Foods</th>
    </tr>`;
var tableEnd = `
  </table>`;

function foods(foods) {
  return `
<h4>Favorite Foods</h4>
<ul class="foods-list">
${foods.map(food => `<li>${food}</li>`).join("")}
</ul>
`;
}

function petTemplate(pet) {
  return `
      <tr>
        <td>${pet.name}</td>
        <td>${pet.species }</td>
        <td>${pet.birthYear}</td>
        <td>${pet.favFoods ? foods(pet.favFoods) : ""}</td>
      </tr>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = `
  ${tableStart}
  ${petsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
  ${tableEnd}
`;
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnCats">cats</button>
<button id="btnDogs">dogs</button>
<div id="table"></div>
```

This is the code that I use to make my json file into a table. How could I have a button that shows the dogs and one that shows the cats in my table?

Comment: You can use JavaScript ```filter()```. This might help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/filtering-json-object/244160/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addd this code

```
var catButton = document.getElementById("btnCats");
    var dogButton=document.getElementById("btnDogs");

catButton.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{

  let catsData=petsData=petsData.filter(value=>
        value.species=="Cat");
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = `
  ${tableStart}
  ${catsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
  ${tableEnd}
`;

});

dogButton.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
   let dogsData=petsData.filter(value=>
        value.species=="Dog");
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = `
  ${tableStart}
  ${dogsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
  ${tableEnd}
`;

});
```

It would be better if you can create a function and use it for the above code

some thing like this

```
function drawTable(){
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = `
  ${tableStart}
  ${petsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
  ${tableEnd}
`;
}
```

So You could use it as

```
dogButton.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
        petsData=petsData.filter(value=>
            value.species=="Dog");
    drawTable();

    });
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but when i load a table with let's say the cats, I can't load directly a table with the dogs, i have to refresh the page first. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Ok use a temporary variable to hold data ill edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can write oncick in this way

Click me!

if you want to call any function let's say sortedFun which sorts the value than you can call the function as

Click me!
make sure that sortedFun() is written in js and js code is loaded.

Comment: And it's better you can add a tempory variable to hold the data and use it as the argument to create the table instead of directly passing it to create the table

Comment: yeah that's why I asked you to keep a temporary variable  for holding the data